# How to convert a string to python object?

Tags: python, django

So, I have got this piece of string:

```py
"[{'id': 45, 'user_id': 2, 'cart_item_id': UUID('0fdc9e75-3d9c-4b89-912b-7058e1233432'), 'quantity': 1}]"
```

And i want to convert it to `list` of `dict` in python
Can anyone please help me out

Comment: isn't a string a python object already?

Comment: well in the question its already a list of dictionaries? @Aditya did you forget the ' '?

Comment: one way is to write this string to a file

Answer (score 5):

A nice way would be using [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

```
my_obj = eval(your_string)
```

A not very nice, but a bit safer way would be parsing it as `json`. But quotes have to be handled first:

```
my_obj = json.loads(your_string.replace("'", '"')
```

Option 1 has to be used with caution as `eval` will evaluate any python code and thus is prone to attacks.
Option 2 is ok, but a corner case with quotes is to be expected.

Comment: Also, `True`, `False`, `None`, and numerics, like `nan`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  def Convert(string):
        li = list(string.split("-"))
        return li
      
    # Driver code    
    str1 = "[{'id': 45, 'user_id': 2, 'cart_item_id': UUID('0fdc9e75-3d9c-4b89-912b-7058e1233432'), 'quantity': 1}]"
    print(Convert(str1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`eval`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) to evaluate your string to object. Just make sure the classes used/present in the string are available in the local or global namespace.

```
from uuid import UUID

output = eval(
    """[{'id': 45, 'user_id': 2, 'cart_item_id': UUID('0fdc9e75-3d9c-4b89-912b-7058e1233432'), 'quantity': 1}]""",
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to do that:

```
string = "[{'id': 45, 'user_id': 2, 'cart_item_id': UUID('0fdc9e75-3d9c-4b89-912b-7058e1233432'), 'quantity': 1}]"


with open('your_file.py') as file:
    data = file.read()

with open('your_file.py', 'w') as file:
    file.write(f'list_ = {string}\n{data}')
```

this will literally add the list to the file.